# Continuous crawl doesn't complete

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

We have Sharepoint Server 2016 running with incremental crawl set for every 5 mins and full crawl everyday. Realised this could cause a problem so changed the crawl type to Continuous Crawl as recommended by Microsoft support.

However, since changed to CC, it just shows as forever running without a completion time. The first run completed in 22 hours, second one still going on for 24 hours now without a completion time. Is this normal for Continuous Crawl? Ms Support said it could require some folder paths to be added to AntiVirus settings, but i am not sure if that's the cause. Everything else seems normal, there's no search error, and new indexes are being searchable. May be that's how Continuous work?

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal behavior for Continuous Crawl.

It will 'forever' run. Do not schedule full crawls.